# Cannot start tensorboard from console due to numpy issue

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorboard

I'd like to make use of TensorBoard.I already saved training and validation data in the same directory as the rest of the project data using the **tensorflow.keras.callbacks** library.

I already pip reinstalled numpy, didn't work out. Then I deleted tb-nightly and tensorboard as I had them both for some reason and just pip reinstalled tb-nightly.

```
(Tensorflow) C:\Users\alias>python -c "print(__import__('numpy').__version__)"
1.16.2

(Tensorflow) C:\Users\alias>python -c "print(__import__('tensorflow').__version__)"
2.0.0-alpha0

(Tensorflow) C:\Users\alias>python -c "print(__import__('tensorboard.version').version.VERSION)"
1.14.0a20190301
```

When calling it via Anaconda prompt on a Win10-OS , the following happens:

```
(Tensorflow) C:\Users\alias>tensorboard --logdir=logs\
TensorBoard 1.14.0a20190301 at http://LAPTOP-4E1BJCAV:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\alias\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 58, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 228, in main
    self._register_info(server)
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 274, in _register_info
    manager.write_info_file(info)
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 269, in write_info_file
    payload = "%s\n" % _info_to_string(tensorboard_info)
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 129, in _info_to_string
    for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 129, in <dictcomp>
    for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
  File "c:\users\alias\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 51, in <lambda>
    (dt - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()),
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Would be glad about some help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a fresh install and or update recently?

Not sure if this applies to your case or not?  Yesterday I installed the latest conda, for python 2.7, from scratch and updated to the latest packages after installation.  Running python from pycharm or windows powershell and importing numpy would throw a multiarray import error.  The fix for me was to downgrade numpy from ?1.16.12? to ?1.5.14?.  Sorry, but I am away from my PC's were I encountered the error but I think those versions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error in my local Jupyter notebook. Upgrading Numpy package worked for me.
Try upgrading Numpy as below

`pip install numpy==1.16`

If the above doesn't work, upgrade tensorflow with below command and try again

`pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

Comment: Sry for the late reply (had to travel much for work): already pip reinstalled numpy to the latest version available:

I then deleted tensorboard and tb-nightly (which I had both for some reason) and just pip reinstalled tb-nightly that appeared transformed the numpy issue into anew one

Comment: Are you using windows. This kind of compatibility issues usually happens in windows OS. Both tensonboard and tb-nightly are included in Tensorflow packages. You might try upgrading Tensorflow or clean reinstall of tensorflow might work. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved @ Github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2092

Thanks for the support